# speed up groupby.apply pandas matching

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe of points on a cartesian plane with IDs ( in this case colours), and a set of circles defined on this same plane their central locations. The circles all have a radius of 2 units.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: points_df = pd.DataFrame([['green', 10., 10., 100],
               ['green', 5, 5, 200],
               ['blue', 9, 9, 3000 ],
               ['blue', 8, 8, 4000]], columns = ['color', 'x', 'y', 'height' ])

In [4]: points_df    
    color   x   y   height
0   green   10.0    10.0    100
1   green   5.0 5.0 200
2   blue    9.0 9.0 3000
3   blue    8.0 8.0 4000

In [5]: circles = np.array([[10, 10], [5, 5], [9,9], [8,8]])
```

For each circle, I'd like to find the entries in the points dataframe *for each color* which fall into the circles. If there are more than one entry per color, I'd then like to find the largest 'height' value in this circle.

For the sake of simplicity let's just assume I have a function `point_selection` which takes a dataframe and a row from the `circles` array and performs this selection. I then apply this function to my dataframe as such:

```
def point_selection(df, circle):
    #distance calculation and selection here
    return selected_df_row

groupby_color = points_df.groupby('color')
df_list = []

for circle in circles:
    selected = groupby_color.apply(point_selection, circle)
    df_list.append(selected.set_index('color', inplace=True))

final_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

I'm currently performing this for a large number of rows in the dataframe (~200000) and a large number of circles (~15000), does anyone have any easy methods to speed up these calculations? Supposedly `groupby.apply` is rather slow, but I can't think of another way to do this.

Comment: Is possible simplify function `point_selection` for testing?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need:

```
def point_selection(df, circle):
    #distance calculation and selection here
    return pd.Series(selected_df_row)

df = points_df.groupby('color').apply(point_selection, circle)
```